# string.replace not working in node.js express server

Tags: javascript, string, file, node.js, express

I need to read a file and replace some texts in that file with dynamic content.when i tried string.replace it is not working for the data that i read from the file.But for the string it is working.I am using node.js and express.

```
fs.readFile('test.html', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
                console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        var msg = data.toString();
        msg.replace("%name%", "myname");
        msg.replace(/%email%/gi, 'example@gmail.com');

        temp = "Hello %NAME%, would you like some %DRINK%?";
        temp = temp.replace(/%NAME%/gi,"Myname");
        temp = temp.replace("%DRINK%","tea");
        console.log("temp: "+temp);
        console.log("msg: "+msg);
    }
});
```

Output:

```
temp: Hello Myname, would you like some tea?
msg: Hello %NAME%, would you like some %DRINK%?
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
msg = msg.replace(/%name%/gi, "myname");
```

You're passing a string instead of a regex to the first replace, and it doesn't match because the case is different. Even if it did match, you're not reassigning this modified value to `msg`. This is strange, because you're doing everything correctly for `tmp`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign variable for `.replace()` which returns the string. In your case, you need to do like, `msg = msg.replace("%name%", "myname");`

Code:

```
fs.readFile('test.html', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
                console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        var msg = data.toString();
        msg = msg.replace("%name%", "myname"); 
        msg = msg.replace(/%email%/gi, 'example@gmail.com');

        temp = "Hello %NAME%, would you like some %DRINK%?";
        temp = temp.replace(/%NAME%/gi,"Myname");
        temp = temp.replace("%DRINK%","tea");
        console.log("temp: "+temp);
        console.log("msg: "+msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: simple.toString() to the rescue.  All the other answers neglect this brilliant simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

`replace()` returns a new string with the replaced substrings, so you must assign that to a variable in order to access it. It does not mutate the original string.

You would want to write the transformed string back to your file.